# My navigation drawer doesn't show up and i get an Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a navigation drawer, i have an issue where the page loads and the hamburger icon shows up. When i click the icon however, it changes into an arrow like it always does, but my drawer does not show up. and when i try to force one of the fragments to show up by default i get an Error inflating class fragment error.

Below is my page layout that holds the drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".app.index">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar">
    </include>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_drwr_fragment"
            class="com.mobile.map.mapversion20.helpers.NavDrawerManager"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/nav_drawer_layout"
            tools:layout="@layout/nav_drawer_layout"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my drawer layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Down here is my Fragment manager

```
public class NavDrawerManager extends Fragment
{
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_layout, container, false);

        setUpRecyclerView(view);

        return view;
    }
    private void setUpRecyclerView(View view) {

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

        NavDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), drawerItem.getData());
        NavDrawerManager manager = new NavDrawerManager();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        if(isLaunch)
        {
            isLaunch = false;
            manager.selectItem("DashBoard");
        }
    }


    public void setUpDrawer(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
//                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
//                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                // Do something of Slide of Drawer
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }
    public void selectItem(String title)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

        switch (title)
        {
            case "Dashboard":
                Fragment dashFragment = new dashboard();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame,dashFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case "Profile":
                Fragment profileFragment = new profile();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame,profileFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case "Notifications":
                Fragment notificationsFragment = new notifications();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame,notificationsFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case "Contact":
                Fragment contactFragment = new contact();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame,contactFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;
            default:
                Fragment defaultFrag = new dashboard();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame,defaultFrag)
                        .commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the error logcat here ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you need to make the DrawerLayout as the parent of you layout file like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->   
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/content_frame"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_drwr_fragment"
        class="com.mobile.map.mapversion20.helpers.NavDrawerManager"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/nav_drawer_layout"
        tools:layout="@layout/nav_drawer_layout"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```